# Decision tree training for Multi-View face detection

Tags: algorithm, opencv, face-detection, decision-tree

I am working for multi-view face detection and following the Jones's multiple-view face detection algorithm.

In the paper ["Fast Multi-view Face Detection"](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/Paper/2371001.aspx), Jones trained C4.5 decision tree with images of different face poses. In Section 3.3 of Decision Tree Training, it is mentioned as "the training algorithm is almost identical to the boosting algorithm. The two main differences are the criteria for feature selection and the splitting of the training set at each node"

I learned and understood C4.5 algorithm [here](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~dbd/cs831/notes/ml/dtrees/c4.5/c4.5_prob1.html).

I can't figure out how to train images of different face poses for C4.5 decision tree.

EDIT 1:
Stage 0 and Stage 1 features of training the ADABOOST algorithm for cascade classifier is shown below.

```
<!-- stage 0 -->
    <_>
      <maxWeakCount>3</maxWeakCount>
      <stageThreshold>-0.7520892024040222</stageThreshold>
      <weakClassifiers>
        <!-- tree 0 -->
        <_>
          <internalNodes>
            0 -1 46 -67130709 -21569 -1426120013 -1275125205 -21585
            -16385 587145899 -24005</internalNodes>
          <leafValues>
            -0.6543210148811340 0.8888888955116272</leafValues></_>
        <!-- tree 1 -->
        <_>
          <internalNodes>
            0 -1 13 -163512766 -769593758 -10027009 -262145 -514457854
            -193593353 -524289 -1</internalNodes>
          <leafValues>
            -0.7739216089248657 0.7278633713722229</leafValues></_>
        <!-- tree 2 -->
        <_>
          <internalNodes>
            0 -1 2 -363936790 -893203669 -1337948010 -136907894
            1088782736 -134217726 -741544961 -1590337</internalNodes>
          <leafValues>
            -0.7068563103675842 0.6761534214019775</leafValues></_></weakClassifiers></_>
    <!-- stage 1 -->
    <_>
      <maxWeakCount>4</maxWeakCount>
      <stageThreshold>-0.4872078299522400</stageThreshold>
      <weakClassifiers>
        <!-- tree 0 -->
        <_>
          <internalNodes>
            0 -1 84 2147483647 1946124287 -536870913 2147450879
            738132490 1061101567 243204619 2147446655</internalNodes>
          <leafValues>
            -0.8083735704421997 0.7685696482658386</leafValues></_>
        <!-- tree 1 -->
        <_>
          <internalNodes>
            0 -1 21 2147483647 263176079 1879048191 254749487 1879048191
            -134252545 -268435457 801111999</internalNodes>
          <leafValues>
            -0.7698410153388977 0.6592915654182434</leafValues></_>
        <!-- tree 2 -->
        <_>
          <internalNodes>
            0 -1 106 -98110272 1610939566 -285484400 -850010381
            -189334372 -1671954433 -571026695 -262145</internalNodes>
          <leafValues>
            -0.7506558895111084 0.5444605946540833</leafValues></_>
        <!-- tree 3 -->
        <_>
          <internalNodes>
            0 -1 48 -798690576 -131075 1095771153 -237144073 -65569 -1
            -216727745 -69206049</internalNodes>
          <leafValues>
            -0.7775990366935730 0.5465461611747742</leafValues></_></weakClassifiers></_>
```

EDIT2:

My consideration for how to train the decision is described in the following picture
[image]
I am still figuring out what are the features to use, but I think the training should be as shown in the attached image.
Thanks

Comment: What is it exactly that you dont understand?

Comment: @remi We need attributes to train decision tree. What are the attributes I have to use? I know how to train boosted cascaded classifier  with Haar features or LBP features. Boost the weight at every iteration and stop the iteration once FA is acceptable. For C4.5 decision tree, I need attributes and values to train. So what are the attributes to train the decision tree.

Comment: @remi Then Jones said  "training algorithm is almost identical to the boosting algorithm". How could be the same training?

Comment: From the ADABOOST training I received selected features in XML files for 20 stages. Stage 0 and Stage 1 are shown in the edit1. Are these features used for training the decision tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not read the paper but frm what I know from early face recognition experiments, the attributes you are looking for are probably just the grey level inputs of the face images. Usually, images are rescaled, say to 32x32 pixels, so you have a 1024 dimensionnal vector to train your decision tree. Have a closer look at the article if they use other features, they will be written, or at least given a reference to?

Comment: I can accept your explanation in the sense that you mean we need to use features (in your case 32x32 gray pixels) to train the decision tree. I contacted Jones and he said he used the same features used for cascaded classifier. So I describe examples of features used for cascaded classifier in EDIT1. They are in internalNodes, leafValues and threshold. I am still debugging detection_based_tracker.cpp so I still don't understand, how these are used and what is the real features. So the way I understand, I describe in EDIT2. (to be continued)

Comment: Say I have 100 features(attributes) for each images.I will have different ranges of values for different face poses. Then if I have 1000 images for frontface, I'll have 1000 rows for that face poses. Then I train that table for the C4.5 decision tree. Is that make sense for you? C4.5 can classify multiple classes, right? Jones said he is busy, so I can't ask him in detail.

Comment: Yes it seems ok. Input to the training will be a 1000x100 matrix (assuming descriptors are stored row-wise) + labels. And decision trees do handle multiple class